# Create a .exe file from python code to open on linux and/or raspbian

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, exe

I'm really noob using python.
I created a GUI interface program with python3 on Windows (Pycharm). How can i execute the program in ubuntu or raspbian like an app?
Thank you.

Comment: Python is an interpreted languange. That means you don't create an executable binary. You install Python on Ubuntu or Raspbian and run your program.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want it to be an `.exe`. If you have created your Python program, then you can execute it simply by running

```
python3 your_program.py
```

from the directory of where the main Python entry file is for your program.

Comment: is it possible to transfer just one file to an ubuntu pc and run all my code without showing them?

Comment: What do you mean "without showing them"? You would need to have the whole code that is needed on the machine to run it. Otherwise, you would have to [package your program as a module and publish it on a repository](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) (such as PyPi) and import it in a new program. This would obfuscate your code but make your task much more complicated.

Comment: i think that's exactly what I want. I'm sorry, as I said, I'm really noob at this. My final interface is a  CNC controller to put in a raspberry with touchscreen that don't belong to me. I wanted to make something like  a github programs, only with .txt files when you open and an exe.